# Applying bubble sort on linked list gives wrong output in c

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to sort a linked list using bubble sort.But it gives segmentation problem

My logic to do so is below:

**Note: Please note that i have to use only pass by reference every where (no return and global declaration for nodes)**

```
void bubble_sort(node * * List, int size) 
{
    int i, j, temp;
    node * first;
    node * second;
    node * final;
    final=*List

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
      first =final;
      second = first -> link;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) 
        {

            if (first -> data < second -> data)
            {
                temp = first -> data;
                first -> data = second -> data;
                second -> data = temp;
            }
            first = first -> link;
        }
    } * List = first;
}
```

It's function call is :

```
bubble_sort(&start,val);
```

**Could any one please help me in correcting the logic ?**

EDIT: My full code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

/* structure containing a data part and link part */
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node * link;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * start, * visit, * newnode;
//start=NULL
///////////////////////////////// Function declaration  ///////////////////
void append(node * * q, int num);
void displaylist(node * start);
void bubble_sort(node * * List, int val);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void append(node * * q, int num)
 {
    node * temp, * temp2;
    temp = * q;
    //temp= (node* )malloc(sizeof (node));
    if (temp == NULL) /* if the list is empty, create first node */
    {
        temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); * q = temp;
    } else
    {
        temp2 = * q;
        while (temp2 -> link != NULL) 
        {
            temp2 = temp2 -> link;
        }
        temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp2 -> link = temp;
    }
    temp -> data = num;
    temp -> link = NULL;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void displaylist(node * start) 
{
    visit = start;
    /* traverse the entire linked list */
    while (visit != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d ", visit -> data);
        visit = visit -> link;
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
void bubble_sort(node **List,int size)
{
int i,j,temp;
node*first;
node*second;
node*final;
final=*List;
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{
first=final;
second=first->link;
for(j=1;j<size;j++)
{

   if( first->data<second->data)
   {
        temp=first->data;
        first->data=second->data;
        second->data=temp;   
    }
   first=first->link;
   }
}
*List=first;
}   */
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void bubble_sort(node * * List, int size)
 {
    int i, j, temp;
    node * first;
    node * second;
    node * final;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        first = * List;
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) 
        {
            if (first -> data < first -> link -> data) 
            {
                temp = first -> data;
                first -> data = first -> link -> data;
                first -> link -> data = temp;
            }
            first = first -> link;
        }
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
main() 
{
    start = NULL;
    int val, n, size;
    char ch;
    struct node * new;
    new = NULL;
    printf("\nEnter the size desired size of Linked list: \n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    for (ch = 0; ch < size; ch++) 
    {
        printf("\nEnter a value: ");
        scanf("%d", & val);
        append( & new, val);
    }
    start = new;
    displaylist(start);
    printf("\nApplying Bubble sort on Linked list: \n");
    bubble_sort( & start, val);
    displaylist(start);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Today would be a good day to learn how to use a debugger. Step through your program and verify on *every* line that the action of the program is correct. When it is not, there's your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed Val is number of nodes in list, you are actually not sorting a linked list but instead swapping the values from one node to another in order to sort it.

```
bubble_sort( &start, size); change this as well should fix it(pass size not val)
```

try this.

```
void bubble_sort(node **List, int val)
{
int i,j,temp;
node *first;
node *second;
node *final;
for(i = 0; i < val; i++)
{
 first = *list
 for(j = 0; j < val-1; j++)
    {
        if(first->data < first->link->data)
        {
            temp = first->data;
            first->data = first->link->data;
            first->link->data = temp;    
        }
        first = first->link;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it also gives sgmentation problem

Comment: I have edited the question to add full code.Could you please check out ?

Comment: you are passing val to bubble sort, pass size not val

Comment: it's size Not val .The name of variable is "val" but it's size

Comment: scanf("%d", &size); this is the size of your list so pass size

Comment: Ohh My Bad... You are right thank you so much.. small problem took me hours. Headache :)

Comment: use gdb next time, it will take you 5 minutes :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48978/discussion-between-user234839-and-tesseract)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting a segmentation fault because you're trying to access a `Null` pointer as a node, in the inner for-loop.

```
for (j = 0; j < val; j++)
```

this should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < val - 1; j++)
```

Because in your solution, when `j = val-1`, it will still try and access `first->link->data`, however, `first->link` is `Null`.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have already done what you just said but still the same problem you can see my full code, I have just eited the question